# How to embed a LDAP server to provide custom data

Tags: java, ldap, embed

I use a closed source application that can be configured to use a LDAP directory for getting group memberships of a user. The LDAP query can be configured at will.
Now I need to integrate various sources that come from applications that provide an API.

I would be able to do this (pseudo code)

```
String[] getGroupmembershipsFromAll( String username ) {
  String[] groups = new String[];

  groups.add( ApiForAppOne.getUserGroups( username ) );
  groups.add( ApiForAppTwo.getUserGroups( username ) );
  groups.add( ApiForAppThree.getUserGroups( username ) );

  return groups;
}
```

My idea is to expose this function via "something" that implements the LDAP RFC. The final step would then to be configure the application with servername:389 and this query:

```
(username='username@domain')
```

(The common criterion that all sources use to identify the user is the Windows AD principal in the form user@domain)

Do you know of a way to achieve this ? Implementing RFC4511 could be the solution but I don't want to start from scratch because the RFC is quite lengthy. Perhaps it is a viable solution to build something based on OpenDS/OpenDJ or ApacheDS but I have no idea they were designed with this in mind. On the other side an elegant solution might be persisting the API results in the LDAP but I don't know if this data must be retrieved using JPA again or if its valid to retrieve it using a LDAP query. I read something about the uboundid LDAP server SDK, perhaps this is another option.

All of this are just ideas, I have no experience in this area. Ideas are very appreciated.

---

Thanks a lot for this information. I took a look at unboundid sdk and the example that starts up a ldap server and imports a ldif.
But your remarks about productive use make me think I perhaps consider a different solution although I definitely will come back to unboundid when I need to write jndi or ldap unit tests.

I'm now able to describe my needs better, perhaps this can be achieved by unboundid or you know another solution that makes me achieve this.
I will need to intercept queries, then invoke the API (see example above) in order to retrieve the data and then feed it to the underlying ldap directory. Perhaps unboundid offers an interface to this. Do you know something about this ? Or more about the design of ApacheDS ?
The reason for this interception is that the applications I can query contain some 100000 entries and I only want to copy those to the ldap who are needed.

Writing about this I see another option: perhaps it is possible to do some aop in order to intercept the call. What do you think ?

Comment: What does this phrase mean "intercept queries"? Intercept from what?

Comment: I want my program to get called when a ldap query comes into the ldap server.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the explanation. The [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/), used with the [UnboundID Server SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/server-sdk.php), supports this functionality when used with the UnboundID Directory Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a real LDAP server I would certainly do that: you will find it a huge step forward. OpenLDAP for example works well and the price is right.

Otherwise there already are embedded LDAP servers out there. The UnboundID SDK that @Terry Gardner often spruiks here contains one of them. I have no affiliation: he may.

Comment: I agree. Use a non-embedded server for this application. The UnboundID LDAP SDK does provide an in-memory server, but it us not designed for production use, more for application testing.

Comment: @TerryGardner See revised question. Does the UnboundID SDK listen at a port? And does it support interception?

Comment: It's a full-fledged server, so it listens on a port and is fully LDAP-compliant. I don't know what "intercept LDAP queries" means, though.

Comment: @TerryGardner See the amended post. She wants to intercept the queries, adjust them, and maybe send them to a real backend or else to this embedded thing, not clear which.

Comment: The three backends I want to integrate provide loads of data of which only a fragment is needed. This is why I want to intercept the query to the ldap, search the backends via their API and then load this data into the ldap and then let the query commence. I think ApacheDS provides interceptors for this but I don't know yet if I can use them to implement my idea (I posted a question to their developer list).

Comment: @Marged You could always constrain your searches a bit more! e.g. only name the attributes you really want.

Comment: @Marged Another way to do all this would be to use OpenLDAP as a standalone server with the Translucent Proxy module and the LDAP backend, so that it receives the queries, gets the results from the backend, modifies what it receives according to the TL configuration, and returns the result to the caller. The TL overlay can add or modify attributes. See http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Translucent%20Proxy. You should also look at the `meta` backend which allows you to remap object classes and attribute names.

Answer (score 0):

[ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/) can do this, but in Node.js, not Java. [ruby-ldapserver](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-ldapserver) is similar, but in Ruby. I am currently searching for an analogue in Java.

Comment: Probably Apache Directory can help here?